# How do I perform row wise comparison of numbers in an R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like shown below.

```
SampleDF <- structure(list(FirstVal = c(100, 230, 450, 600), SecondVal = c(566, 
547, 557, 250), ThirdVal = c(782, 479, 823, 178), LowerLimit = c(10, 
15, 22, 50), UpperLimit = c(600, 500, 600, 500)), .Names = c("FirstVal", 
"SecondVal", "ThirdVal", "LowerLimit", "UpperLimit"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have columns named `FirstVal, SecondVal and ThirdVal` and two calculated columns `UpperLimit and LowerLimit`.

I am trying to pick elements from each row, that fall within the Lower and Upper Limits and discard any element beyond UpperLimit. After eliminating so, I want to find out which element is the largest among the remaining and add it in a new column.

Additionally, I wish to add the column name along with it. I have tried doing so by transposing my original dataframe but I have a trouble referencing my original columns.

How do I perform a row-wise comparisons in R?

---

Expected Output :

```
SampleDFNew
  FirstVal SecondVal ThirdVal LowerLimit UpperLimit MaxValBelowUpperLim ColumnName
1      100       566      782         10        600                 566  SecondVal
2      230       547      479         15        500                 479   ThirdVal
3      450       557      823         22        600                 557  SecondVal
4      600       250      178         50        500                 250  SecondVal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works!

1.First find out values which doesn't fall into the limits and remove them.

2.Find which among other elements is max and extract names from colnames.

```
 x<-sapply(SampleDF[,1:3],function(x) ifelse(x > SampleDF$LowerLimit & x < SampleDF$UpperLimit,x,NA))

SampleDf$Columnname <-  colnames(x)[apply(x,1,which.max)]
```

Comment: Why is it giving the below error if I try to use the above process inside of a function (shiny reactive or a simple function) ? `Error in colnames(x_r)[apply(x_r, 1, which.max)] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
tmp<-(SampleDF[,1:3]>=SampleDF$LowerLimit & SampleDF[,1:3]<=SampleDF$UpperLimit)*as.matrix(SampleDF[,1:3])
colnames(SampleDF[,1:3])[max.col(tmp*NA^(rowSums(tmp)==0))]
#[1] "SecondVal" "ThirdVal"  "SecondVal" "SecondVal"
```

Comment: No problem with that, glad it helped. Consider also that my solution is vectorized and should be much faster.

Comment: Yes indeed..It is faster.